# Getting 400 error Bad request using axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am using axios and getting a 400 bad request error. I am using react-redux and trying to send a post request to localhost:3000/posts. Here is the code that I am using.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  GET_ALL_POSTS,
  GET_POST,
  CREATE_POST,
  DELETE_POST,
  UPDATE_POST
} from './types';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export function createPost({content, title}, cb) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts`, {content, title})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_POST,
          payload: response
        });
      })
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Problem submitting New Post", error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `.catch()`, what is the full text of the error that is logging to the console? And can you get any info from the server? Like, if you're using Express, what do you get if you `console.log(req)` in the call to `app.post('/posts', (req, res){})`?

Comment: Problem submitting New Post Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (bundle.js:29014)
    at settle (bundle.js:37974)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (bundle.js:28850)

is the error and if I console.log(req) I dont even get to that point. Its as if nothing is getting sent to the server.   @skwidbreth

Comment: Hmm - it seems that you're not the first person to encounter this issue. See this post - https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/376 - it looks like there might be a helpful answer all the way at the bottom.

Comment: @skwidbreth they dont seem to be getting the 400 error, it looks like they are trying to deal with error handling. For some reason my data is not getting posted to the server at all. I dont think changing how the error is explained will fix my problem.

Comment: It is on wifi, and everything is running just fine. My server says its running on port 3000 and my client is running using webpack on 8080. I can make post request just fine to my localhost:3000/signin, but when it comes to /posts it is giving me a bad request if I console.log(error.response.data) in the catch

Comment: This bit looks ... questionable `{content, title}` as you have elements without element names. Might be worth hard-coding the request first off to something like `{ content:"hello", title:"world" }` to see if that modifies the 400 error??  Or possibly try it with just the one element `axios.post (url, content).then...`

Comment: @GregHNZ I tried all this and still got the 400 bad request error.

Comment: @GregHNZ I used postman and sent a request to localhost:3000/posts and still got bad request so this may not be axios

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue.  Try the chrome extension: Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: @genestd I am using the npm package cors and include it in my index.js and use app.use(cors());

Answer (score 4):

i was also getting this error, the issue was not with server or with axios or proxy url.
The issue was i wasn't sending the correct data from my react application.
For Example
i supposed to send:
`{ email: 'ib2@gmail.com', password: 'asdf' }`

what i was sending is:
`{ name: 'ib2@gmail.com', password: 'asdf' }`

this caused api don't understand name field, as i provided email as the key in api.

so if you are still facing the issue try to check if you are sending the correct data.

Comment: That's relatable!! I was sending a raw query string and forgot the `=` at the end. I.e, `?id123` instead of `?id=123`

Answer (score 3):

For every post request, the client first sends an OPTIONS request to check whether the server is ready to accept the connection. You should also allow the server to accept options request. If you have not allowed use the below lines in case of node server

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
      next();
});
```