# Request made with axios does not work but if it works with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm doing a Request from react with axios, that request looks like this:

```
const data= axios.post(route, { username:'admin', password:'123' })
              .then(response =>{
                console.log(response)
              })
              .catch(err=>{console.log(err.response)

          })
```

But it gives me back status 400 or 401. I thought it was something with the 'CORS' but when I make the request with XMLHttpRequest from react, it is successful. Here the same request made with XMLHttpRequest:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var user = "admin";
  var password = "123";

  xhr.open('POST', route, true);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var responseObject = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(responseObject);
    if (responseObject.token) {
          console.log(responseObject.token);
    } else {
          console.log('no');
    }
  });

  var sendObject = JSON.stringify({username: user, password: password});

  console.log('going to send', sendObject);

  xhr.send(sendObject);
```

How can I make the request with axios correctly?

Logs:

[image: log]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting 400 error Bad request using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731340/getting-400-error-bad-request-using-axios)

Comment: Doesnt answer my question, I tried with other api of login that i have available and the status changes to 404

Comment: 400 is bad request, 404 is not found, so the structure is incorrect, can you paste the output of `console.log(route)`?

Answer (score 1):

Axios should have a auth parameter, like so:

```
auth: {
    username: 'janedoe',
    password: 's00pers3cret'
},
```

check out the documentation here: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Does your axios.post have a basic authentication? 401 is Unauthorized status

Answer (score 1):

How if you set content type parameter in post request?

Can you try,

```
let config = {
  headers: {
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
  }
}

let response = await axios.post(route, { username:'admin', password:'123' }, config);
console.log(response);
```

Comment: If I add the Content-Type parameter, it keeps returning 400

Comment: Works correctly in postman, in edition of the question i add logs. Status 401

Comment: How if you change the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and send the param with query string?