# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' policy error on sending POST request to REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, post, cors

I am making a simple full-stack project wherein I have a very basic REST API built using NodeJS and Express. It is a server-side rendered website.

While trying to login, when I send a POST request to the login endpoint, I am getting the following error in the console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

This is the code snippet that sends the POST request

```
const login = async (email,password) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
            data: {
                email,
                password
            }
        });    
        if(res.data.status === 'success') {
            alert('Logged in successfully');
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                location.assign('/');
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Please explain as to why I'm getting that error and how to fix it. The API is not deployed yet and it's running on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request origin is:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

This is not the same as the domain you're sending the request to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

To avoid this CORS error, the [FQDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Domain) must be the same, including hostname and port.  (Or you could configure your server for CORS.)  As far as the server is concerned, the different host means a completely separate entity, even if it's the same machine.

Change your url to:

```
url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login',
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it seems to have fix the error related to CORS, but the request is still not successfully executed due to the following error

Error: Request failed with status code 400

    at e.exports (spread.js:25)

    at e.exports (spread.js:25)

    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange (spread.js:25)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731340/getting-400-error-bad-request-using-axios

Answer (score -1):

could you add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the request and see ,

```
const login = async (email,password) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
            headers: {
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
            data: {
                email,
                password
            }
        });    
        if(res.data.status === 'success') {
            alert('Logged in successfully');
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                location.assign('/');
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```